# How to Count in an iOS/macOS/watchOS Shortcut?

Tags: script, shortcuts-app, watchos, automation

It feels fairly ridiculous to me that you can't do a simple increment of a counter inside a shortcut that works with all three major shortcut platforms: iOS/macOS/watchOS.

There is a repeat_count available in a repeat loop, but it is quite limited.

Am I missing something?

-- Christopher Allen

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research, trial, error, the best I have is a hack that works with only default shortcut scripting functions and only within a repeat loop. But it does work on all three platforms (macOS, iOS, and watchOS).

- Use the "Number" verb to create a text item.
- Use the "Add Variable" verb to append the Number to a text variable.
- Use the "Count" verb to count the items in that text variable.

Here is a screenshot example, since there is no 'code' in Shortcuts:

[image: screenshot of an example shortcut].

*(I'm also tracking details at https://gist.github.com/ChristopherA/c910c9fb238c6e0a269565316261fdce)*